# Sparrow for Mac resets after quitting

Tags: macos, sparrow

Every time I quit and relaunch my Sparrow email client I am prompted with the setup screen. All my accounts and preferences are reset. It's as if I just installed the app for the first time again.

I'm not exactly sure how I got the app into this state but reinstalling it does not fix the problem. I have also tried searching my Mac for and deleting all files and folder that contain *sparrow* in the name, and then reinstalling but still no luck.

I've emailed Sparrow support quite some time ago and no response. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Same happening here

Answer (score 2):

Sparrow's development was halted quite a while ago, and as OS X has developed, Sparrow hasn't kept up.

Most notably is the addition of Containers for app's data and I speculate that this is causing some problem with some code in Sparrow. Obviously, this is speculation as I haven't seen Sparrow's source code, but I don't think it's something that you can fix yourself—it's most probably a bug in Sparrow's code.

Comment: I understand both of those things, but I've had Sparrow working fine for a long time under those conditions. I even installed it under those conditions. It crashed one day when adding a new account, and after that it started displaying the above issue. It MUST be possible to install it again, but for some reason there seems to be a file or setting somewhere that has been messed up. A reinstall of OSX I'm sure would fix the issue, but I don't really feel like doing that.

Comment: Does it work if you use it under a newly created OSX account?